# LD script for symbol hidding in c++

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

I would like to use an GNU LD version script to hide unwanted symbols in c++ shared library. Say my header file looks like this:

```
int a();
int a(int);

class B {
    B(){}
    ~B(){}
    int x(int);
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const B& b );
```

I would like to hide everything which is not stated in the header file.

How would a version script for this look like?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
{
global:
    extern "C++" {
        "a()";
        "a(int)";
        B::*;
        "operator<<(std::ostream&, B const&)";
    };
local:
    *;
};
```

If you saved this file as `foo.map`, pass `-Wl,--version-script,foo.map` as an argument to the linker.  A quick rundown of the syntax:

- Since we didn't specify a version label at the top level of the script, the symbols in the library won't have versions attached: the effect of the script is simply to pick which symbols are visible.
- Everything matched by the `global` section will be visible, while everything remaining that matches the `local` section (in this case, the glob `*`) will be hidden.
- The `extern "C++" { ... };` block says the linker should demangle symbols according to the C++ ABI before trying to match against the enclosed patterns.
- Patterns in quotes are matched directly, while unquoted patterns are treated as glob patterns.

More details of the version script file format can be found here: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/VERSION.html

Comment: Anyway to export symbols from `ns::*` but exclude the ones from `ns::internal::*`?

Comment: You can create a set of globs in the version script will do that.  Something like: `"ns::[!i]*"`, `"ns:i[!n]*"`, `"ns:in[!t]*"`, etc.  It might be easier and more precise to use symbol visibility annotations in the source though.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's really brilliant, and it works great! Using annotations in source code might not be as easier as version script, because we have a lot of classes/functions, change them one by one might be awful.

Comment: You'll probably find you need to export a few more symbols that won't match those globs.  In particular typeinfo symbols for RTTI, and vtable symbols if you have virtual functions.  In contrast, a single visibility annotation on a class will export everything related to that class.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, we will evaluate that, symbol visibility annotations are indeed more clear than a version script.