# Hiding symbol names in library

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I want to hide symbol names which are not relevant to the end user and make visible only APIs in my shared or static library. I have a simple code like:

```
int f_b1(){
return 21 ;
}

int f_b3(){
return f_b1() ;
}
```

I applied the all methods stated [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-symbol-visibility/index.html?ca=drs-) such as using `__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))` and `static` but without success. My operating system is Ubuntu on an x86_64 processor. Do I need to use special options while compiling with gcc? I am listing modules and function of libraries with `nm` command. In my example above I only want to make the `f_b3` function visible. When I use `attribute hidden` macro compiler does not give any error but the function still exists in list outputted by the `nm` command.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `visibility("hidden")` attribute does not *suppress* a symbol from
an object file and cannot prevent a symbol being extracted by `nm`. It just
instructs the dynamic linker that the symbol cannot be called from outside
a shared library that contains it.

Consider a source file `file.c` containing your example functions:

```
int f_b1(){
return 21 ;
}

int f_b3(){
return f_b1() ;
}
```

Compile the file:

```
gcc -c -o file.o file.c
```

Run `nm file.o` to list the symbols. Output:

```
0000000000000000 T f_b1
000000000000000b T f_b3
```

Now run `objdump -t file.o` for fuller information about the symbols. Output:

```
file.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 file.c
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack    0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame  0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment   0000000000000000 .comment
0000000000000000 g     F .text  000000000000000b f_b1
000000000000000b g     F .text  000000000000000b f_b3
```

Here we see that `f_b1` and `f_b3` are global (g) functions (F) in the `.text`
section.

Now modify the file like this:

```
__attribute__((visibility ("hidden"))) int f_b1(void){
return 21 ;
}

__attribute__((visibility ("hidden"))) int f_b3(void){
return f_b1() ;
}
```

Run `objdump` again:

```
file.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 file.c
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack    0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame  0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment   0000000000000000 .comment
0000000000000000 g     F .text  000000000000000b .hidden f_b1
000000000000000b g     F .text  000000000000000b .hidden f_b3
```

The output is the same, except that the symbols `f_b1` and `f_b3` are now marked
`.hidden`. They still have external (global) linkage and could be statically called, for
example, from other modules within a library that contains them, but could
not be dymamically called from outside that library.

So, if you want to conceal `f_b1` and `f_b3` from dynamic linkage in a *shared*
library, you can use `visibility ("hidden")` as shown.

If you want to conceal `f_b1` and `f_b3` from *static* linkage in a *static*
library, you cannot use the `visibility` attribute to do that at all.

In the case of a static library, you can "hide" a symbol only be giving it
internal instead of external linkage. The way to do that is by prefixing the
standard `static` keyword. But internal linkage means that the symbol is
visible only within its own *compilation* unit: it can't be referenced from
other modules. It is not available to the linker at all.

Modify `file.c` again, like this:

```
static int f_b1(void){
return 21 ;
}

static int f_b3(void){
return f_b1() ;
}
```

And run `objump` again:

```
file.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 file.c
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l     F .text  000000000000000b f_b1
000000000000000b l     F .text  000000000000000b f_b3
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack    0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame  0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment   0000000000000000 .comment
```

You see that `f_b1` and `f_b3` are still reported as functions in the `.text`
section, but are now classified *local* (l), not global. That is internal linkage. 
Run `nm file.o` and the output is:

```
0000000000000000 t f_b1
000000000000000b t f_b3
```

That is the same as for the original file, except that instead of 'T' flags
we now have 't' flags. Both flags mean that the symbol is in the `.text` section,
but 'T' means it is global and 't' means it is local.

Apparently, what you would like `nm` to report for this file is *no symbols at all*.
You should now understand that `nm file.o` will report a symbol if it exists in
`file.o`, but its existence has got nothing to do with whether it is visible
for static or dynamic linkage.

To make the function symbols *disappear*, compile `file.c` yet again
(still with the `static` keyword), this time with optimisation enabled:

```
gcc -c -O1 -o file.o file.c
```

Now, `objdump` reports:

```
file.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 file.c
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack    0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment   0000000000000000 .comment
```

`f_b1` and `f_b3` are gone, and `nm file.o` reports nothing at all. Why?
Because `static` tells the compiler that these symbols can only be called
from within the file it is compiling, and optimisation decides that there
is no need to refer to them; so *the compiler* eliminates them from the
object code. But if they weren't already invisible to linker, without 
optimisation, then we couldn't optimise them away.

Bottom line: It doesn't matter whether `nm` can extract a symbol. If the
symbol is local/internal, it can't be linked, either statically or dynamically.
If the symbol is marked `.hidden` then it can't be *dynamically* linked. You
can use `visibility("hidden")` to mark a symbol `.hidden`. Use the standard
`static` keyword to make a symbol local/internal.

Comment: Is there a way to hide object file names also? My `nm` command outputs like this.     ```b.o:
0000000000000000 T f_b2
0000000000000010 T f_b3

c.o:
``` I would like to hide `b.o and c.o` names, as well. Thanks..

Comment: Yes: Run `strip -s file.o`. See `man strip`. Note that when you remove all symbols you can't debug the object file.

Comment: `strip -s file.o` removes all symbols, not only can I debug but I also can not use any functions since their symbols does not exists on symbol table. I only need to remove object file names from the library.

Comment: Another problem exists with class methods, that is if a class method's implementation is defined in header file the symbol name does not appear on symbol table. However, if it is defined in `.cpp` file separately they appears, whether they are static or not.

Comment: with `strip --strip-debug libtest.a` it is possible to remove `0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 file.c` section from the library or object file which presents file names but object file names still appears on `nm` command, which shows the section names. I could not remove them yet.

Comment: Re. class member symbols. In C++ a member function defined within the class definition will be inlined if the compiler can reasonably do so; otherwise not, unless the `inline` keyword is applied. If a definition is inlined then it need not be called, so no symbol is needed by which to call it.

Comment: Re. purging filenames. I was referring to `-s|--strip-all`, not `-S|--strip-debug`. Anyway, you can't remove the object filenames from a `.a` archive because it is an archive *of the object files*, and I can't see why you would think you need to.

Comment: As I understand it is not possible to hide class member symbols without changing structure of classes. Using `inline` keyword converts methods to static which can not use internal variables of class which are not static. You again emphasize on `-s|--strip-all` command but it removes all symbols and it makes library unusable since the linker can not find any symbols. Am I missing something here? I only would like to make visible necessary APIs and hide all internal data. Is there a way to change symbol names on an object/library?

Comment: @Mike Kinghan "It doesn't matter whether nm can extract a symbol." I disagree considering the potential desire to obfuscate the library from those who might have an easier time reverse engineering your machine instructions.

Comment: Don't miss the [`--version_script`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21845178/192373) for  GNU **ld** and compatible linkers.

Comment: @Mike Kinghan `objectdump -t libfoo.so | grep -i hidden` outputs nothing, whereas `objectdump -t foo.o | grep -i hidden` outputs many symbols to the console. Why?

Answer (score 12):

I realize this is already an old thread. However, I'd like to share some facts about static linking in the sense of making hidden symbols local and hence prevent those symbols from (global) static linkage in an object file or static library. This does not mean making them invisible in the symbol table.

Mike Kingham's answer is very useful but not complete with respect to the following detail:

> If you want to conceal f_b1 and f_b3 from static linkage in a static
> library, you cannot use the visibility attribute to do that at all.

Let me show that hidden symbols can certainly be made local by using the example of the simple code in `file.c` and applying [ypsu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103855/ypsu)'s answer in [Symbol hiding in static libraries built with Xcode/gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276474/symbol-hiding-in-static-libraries-built-with-xcode-gcc).
As a first step let's reproduce the objdump output with the hidden attribute visible on `f_b1` and `f_b3`. This can be done by the following command, which gives all functions in `file.c` the hidden attribute:

```
gcc -fvisibility=hidden -c file.c
```

Output of `objdump -t file.o` gives

```
file.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 file.c
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack    0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame  0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment   0000000000000000 .comment
0000000000000000 g     F .text  000000000000000b .hidden f_b1
000000000000000b g     F .text  0000000000000010 .hidden f_b3
```

This is exactly the same intermediate result as obtained by Mike Kingham. Now let's make the symbols with the hidden attribute local. That is accomplished by using `objcopy` from `binutils` as follows:

```
objcopy --localize-hidden --strip-unneeded file.o
```

Using objdump, gives

```
file.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l     F .text  000000000000000b .hidden f_b1
000000000000000b l     F .text  0000000000000010 .hidden f_b3
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment   0000000000000000 .comment
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack    0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame  0000000000000000 .eh_frame
```

Likewise, `nm file.o` gives

```
0000000000000000 t f_b1
000000000000000b t f_b3
```

Although `f_b1` and `f_b3` are still visible in the the symbol table they are local. Hence, functions `f_b1` and `f_b3` are concealed from static linking!

I'd also like to add a note on declaring functions static and by that having the possibility to remove them from the symbol table completely. First, the removal can be done deterministically and not depending on compiler optimization by using `objcopy`.

```
objcopy --strip-unneeded file.o
```

The static functions `f_b1` and `f_b2` are not anymore in the symbol table of `file.o`.

Secondly, this use of declaring functions static to let them disappear from the symbol table only works in single source file C-projects. As soon as a C-project consists of many components and hence files this only can be done by merging all C-source and -header files into one single source file and declare all internal interfaces (functions) static with obvious the exception of the global (top) interface. If that is not possible, one can fallback to the method originally described by [ypsu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103855/ypsu) (and probably many others - see for instance [Restricting symbols in a Linux static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393980/restricting-symbols-in-a-linux-static-library)).

Answer (score 1):

Note that for MacOS/iOS the linker has some extra options to control symbol visibility;

- `-[un|re]exported_symbols_list`
- `-[un]exported_symbol`

For more information check e.g. the ld64 documentation or have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2185/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004200-CH1-SUBSECTION5).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in the ELF structure there are 2 symbol tables: "symtab" and "dynsym".
In my custom libs, I'm always stripping *all* the symbols, because they are not needed for proper linking - i.e. the "symtab" (which is printed by the "nm" utility) can be empty, because the linker is actually using the "dynsym" table.
This allows to reduce the lib size by ~10-20% (typically)

The functions with "hidden" attribute are removed only from "symtab", but they can still be visible in the "dynsym" table.

You can verify this by using:

```
readelf --syms --dyn-syms <your dso here>
```

The "dynsym" table always contains all the entries needed by the linker, including f.e. the STD:: functions, marked as "UND" (undefined -> to be resolved by the linker)

Regards.