# Is there any gcc/g++ linker flag than removes the hidden visibility from symbols of a shared library

Tags: linux, qt, gcc, makefile, shared-libraries

I went through this [The hidden visibility does get applied in my shared libraries but works for static libraries on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348030/the-hidden-visibility-does-get-applied-in-my-shared-libraries-but-works-for-static)

and
[Is there any way to override the -fvisibility=hidden at link time？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273404/is-there-any-way-to-override-the-fvisibility-hidden-at-link-time)

but I have follow up question

1. File: `lib_mylib.h`

```
int fun();
int fun1(void);
int fun2(void);
```

2. File: `lib_mylib.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun() {
  return 2; 
}
int fun1(void) {
  return 2; 
}
int fun2(void) {
  return 2;
}
```

3. File: `my_lib_shared.c`

```
#include "my_lib.h"
int foo(void) {
  return fun() + 4;
}
```

4. File: `my_lib_shared.h`

```
int foo();
```

5. File driver.c

```
/* filename: driver.c  */
#include "my_lib.h"
#include "my_lib_shared.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int x = foo() ;
  return 0;
}
```

If I execute following steps

```
1) `gcc -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -c my_lib.c -o lib_mylib.o`
2) `gcc -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -shared -o libMyLibHidden.so lib_mylib.o`
3) `gcc -fPIC -c my_lib_shared.c -o my_lib_shared.o`
4) `gcc -shared -o libMyShared2.so my_lib_shared.o`
5) `gcc -L. -Wall -o test_hidden driver.c -lMyLibHidden -lMyShared2`
```

the output of objdump is as

```
objdump -T libMyLibHidden.so

libMyLibHidden.so:     file format elf64-x86-64

    DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
    0000000000000448 l    d  .init  0000000000000000       .init
    0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000        __gmon_start__
    0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000       _Jv_RegisterClasses
    0000000000000658 g    DF .fini  0000000000000000  Base  _fini
    0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000     _deregisterTMCloneTable
    0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000  _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
    0000000000000000  w   DF *UND*  0000000000000126   GLIBC_2.2.5 _cxa_finalize
    0000000000200938 g    D  *ABS*  0000000000000000  Base        __bss_start
    0000000000200948 g    D  *ABS*  0000000000000000  Base        _end
    0000000000200938 g    D  *ABS*  0000000000000000  Base        _edata
    0000000000000448 g    DF .init  0000000000000000  Base        _init
```

I did not any reference of functions of fun, fun1 and fun2 in the above objdump. Which is expected

and I get following error at final linking step

```
/tmp/ccMsEpFq.o: In function main':
driver.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference tofun' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but in my actual code and shared libraries of `libQtGui.so` i can see in my Makefile `-fvisibility=hidden` is given as flag but still the symbols are available in my dynamic symbol table of `libQtGui.so`

=--------------------------------My question

is is there any flag in gcc linux or way where we can override the hidden visibility and make the symbols available in shared libraries

or there any flag in gcc linux where we can export all the symbols in the shared library

The flags of my Makefile while making shared library of `libQtGui.so` are

```
CFLAGS        = -m64 -pipe -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -m64 -pipe -fpermissive -g -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I../../mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I../../include/QtCore -I../../include/QtCore -I../../include -I../../include/QtGui -I../3rdparty/libpng -I../3rdparty/zlib -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I../3rdparty/harfbuzz/src -Idialogs -I.moc/release-shared -I/usr/X11R6/include -I.uic/release-shared
LINK          = g++

LFLAGS        = -m64 -Wl,-rpath/shared_libary_path -shared -Wl,-soname,libQtGui.so.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `-fvisibility=hidden` flag and all functions will be exported.