# Removing symbols from `.a`s

Tags: linker, ld, symbols, nm

I'm compiling a C++ static library using `g++` via Cmake. I want to remove symbols relating to the internal implementation so they don't show up in `nm`. (See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) and [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/GenerateExportHeader.html) for the same with shared libraries.)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276474/symbol-hiding-in-static-libraries-built-with-xcode-gcc/18949281#18949281) tells you how to do it on iOS, and I'm trying to understand what happens under the hood so I can replicate on Linux. They invoke `ld` with:

- `-r`/`--relocatable` to Generate relocatable output---i.e., generate an output file that can in turn serve as input to ld.
- `-x`/`--discard-all`: Delete all local symbols.

AFAICS the `-r` glues all the modules into one module, and then the `-x` removes symbols only used inside that module. Is that right?

It's not clear how the linker 'knows' which symbols will be exported externally? Does it rely on  `__attribute__((visibility("hidden/default")))` as in the `.so` case?

Edit: clearly I'm confused... I thought cmake invoked `ld` to link the `.o`s into `.a`. Googled + clarified above.

Question still stands: how do I modify the build process to exclude most symbols?

Comment: You cannot create a static library with `ld`. A static library is simply
an archive of object files created with the archiver `ar`. The linker has
no role. Please redescribe your problem correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding symbol names in library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244428/hiding-symbol-names-in-library)