# undefined reference to while linking with shared library

Tags: c++, linker, g++, static-linking

I am trying to write a small program linking against a shared library (*.so).But when I try to compile the program,
I get an error saying 'undefined reference' to "the function"

Content of the program file.

```
user@ubuntu:~/Perforce/user_ubuntu_3105/wp/eng/main/src/libfc/37D03B6/bin$ cat test.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include "InfoModel.h"

int main() 
{
    libfc::InfoModel & model = libfc::InfoModel::instance();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this I get the error 'undefined reference to '

```
user@ubuntu:~/Perforce/user_ubuntu_3105/wp/eng/main/src/libfc/37D03B6/bin$ g++ -Wall -W -std=c++0x test.cpp -L. -lfc -o rst
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:9:21: warning: unused variable ‘model’ [-Wunused-variable]
libfc::InfoModel & model = libfc::InfoModel::instance();
                 ^
/tmp/ccFtLDxc.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `libfc::InfoModel::instance()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But when I look at the symbols in the .so file, I see the symbol there.

```
user@ubuntu:~/Perforce/user_ubuntu_3105/wp/eng/main/src/libfc/37D03B6/bin$ nm --demangle libfc.so | grep InfoModel 
0000000000007e40 t _GLOBAL__sub_I_InfoModel.cpp
00000000002464a0 b guard variable for libfc::InfoModel::instance()::instance_
0000000000010260 t libfc::InfoModel::add_unknown(unsigned int, unsigned short, unsigned short)
0000000000010520 t libfc::InfoModel::registerIEType(libfc::IEType const*)
000000000000f550 t libfc::InfoModel::add(libfc::InfoElement const&)
0000000000012980 t libfc::InfoModel::add(std::string const&)
0000000000010a60 t libfc::InfoModel::instance()
00000000000106f0 t libfc::InfoModel::initTypes()
00000000000108f0 t libfc::InfoModel::InfoModel()
00000000000108f0 t libfc::InfoModel::InfoModel()
0000000000027ae0 t libfc::InfoModel::~InfoModel()
0000000000027ae0 t libfc::InfoModel::~InfoModel()
0000000000010b00 t libfc::InfoModel::parseIESpec(std::string const&) const
000000000000ee80 t libfc::InfoModel::lookupIEType(unsigned int) const
000000000000ed40 t libfc::InfoModel::lookupIEType(std::string const&) const
000000000000ef20 t libfc::InfoModel::dump(std::ostream&) const
000000000000f0c0 t libfc::InfoModel::lookupIE(unsigned int, unsigned short, unsigned short) const
000000000000f1b0 t libfc::InfoModel::lookupIE(libfc::InfoElement const&) const
0000000000012840 t libfc::InfoModel::lookupIE(std::string const&) const
000000000000f410 t libfc::InfoModel::lookupIE2(unsigned int, std::string const&, unsigned short, unsigned short) const
00000000002463a0 b libfc::InfoModel::instance()::instance_
```

I also did this.

```
user@ubuntu:~/Perforce/user_ubuntu_3105/wp/eng/main/src/libfc/37D03B6/bin$ readelf -s libfc.so | grep FILE 
34: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS EncodePlan.cpp
43: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS InfoElement.cpp
49: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS FileExportDestination.cpp
53: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS IETemplate.cpp
58: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS IEType.cpp
104: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS InfoModel.cpp
113: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS libfc.cpp
118: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS PlacementExporter2.cpp
124: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS PlacementTemplate.cpp
129: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS TemplateState.cpp
135: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS test.cpp
141: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS UdpSocketExportDestinatio
149: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
158: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS BasicOctetArray.cpp
159: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS Exception.cpp
160: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS ExportError.cpp
161: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS FormatError.cpp
162: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS IESpecError.cpp
163: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS error_code.cpp
187: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
190: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS
```

Update:
The make file to build this shared library is

```
PLUGIN          = libfc
OUTPUT_DIR      = bin
OUTPUT          = $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(PLUGIN).so
PLUG_SRC        = src
EXCEPTION_SRC   = src/exceptions
CPP             = g++
THIRD_PARTY_DIR = ../../../../../third-party
BOOST_DIR       = $(THIRD_PARTY_DIR)/boost/1.66.0
G3LOG_DIR       = $(THIRD_PARTY_DIR)/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log
FLAGS           = -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread \
              -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive 
MACROS          = -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_
INCLUDES        = -I$(PLUG_SRC) \
              -I$(EXCEPTION_SRC) \
              -I$(BOOST_DIR) \
              -I$(G3LOG_DIR)/src \
              -I$(G3LOG_DIR)/include
LFLAGS          = -shared -lpthread -L$(G3LOG_DIR)/build -lg3logger
CPPFLAGS     = $(FLAGS) $(MACROS) $(INCLUDES)  
LDFLAGS      = $(LFLAGS)
ifeq ($(BUILD),DEBUG)
CPPFLAGS += -ggdb3 -O0 
else
CPPFLAGS += -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG
LDFLAGS += -flto 
endif

# compile static boost lib as
# ./bjam --toolset=gcc address-model=64 cxxflags=-fPIC cflags=-fPIC 
variant=release threading=multi link=static --with-system stage
BOOST_LIBS      = $(BOOST_DIR)/stage/lib/libboost_system.a
OBJ_DIR         = obj
PLUG_OBJS       = $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(subst 
$(PLUG_SRC)/,,$(wildcard $(PLUG_SRC)/*.cpp)))
FRAME_OBJS      = $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(subst 
$(EXCEPTION_SRC)/,,$(wildcard $(EXCEPTION_SRC)/*.cpp)))
VPATH           = $(PLUG_SRC) $(EXCEPTION_SRC)

all: $(PLUGIN)
$(PLUG_OBJS): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
   $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
$(FRAME_OBJS): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
   $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
$(PLUG_OBJS) $(FRAME_OBJS): | $(OBJ_DIR)
$(OBJ_DIR):
   mkdir $(OBJ_DIR)
$(OUTPUT): | $(OUTPUT_DIR)
$(OUTPUT_DIR):
   mkdir $(OUTPUT_DIR)
$(PLUGIN): $(PLUG_OBJS) $(FRAME_OBJS) $(OUTPUT)
   $(CPP) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(OUTPUT)  $(PLUG_OBJS) $(FRAME_OBJS) $(BOOST_LIBS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
   rm -f $(PLUG_OBJS) $(FRAME_OBJS) $(OUTPUT)
   rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
   rm -rf $(OUTPUT_DIR)
```

And the output of make is

```
user@ubuntu:~/Perforce/sselvam_ubuntu_3105/wp/eng/main/src/libfc/37D03B6$ make all 
mkdir obj
g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/BasicOctetArray.o src/BasicOctetArray.cpp
g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/EncodePlan.o src/EncodePlan.cpp
src/EncodePlan.cpp: In constructor ‘libfc::EncodePlan2::EncodePlan2(const libfc::PlacementTemplate*)’:
src/EncodePlan.cpp:90:9: warning: unused variable ‘ie_present’ [-Wunused-variable]
bool ie_present
     ^
g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/FileExportDestination.o src/FileExportDestination.cpp
g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/IETemplate.o src/IETemplate.cpp
 g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/IEType.o src/IEType.cpp
 g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/InfoElement.o src/InfoElement.cpp
g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/InfoModel.o src/InfoModel.cpp
g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/libfc.o src/libfc.cpp
g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/PlacementExporter2.o src/PlacementExporter2.cpp
g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/PlacementTemplate.o src/PlacementTemplate.cpp
g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/TemplateState.o src/TemplateState.cpp
g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/UdpSocketExportDestination.o src/UdpSocketExportDestination.cpp
g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/Exception.o src/exceptions/Exception.cpp
g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/ExportError.o src/exceptions/ExportError.cpp
g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/FormatError.o src/exceptions/FormatError.cpp
g++ -c -std=c++0x -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -pthread -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive  -D_libfc_HAVE_NIXIO -U_libfc_HAVE_LOG4CPLUS_ -U_libfc_HAVE_WANDIO_ -Isrc -Isrc/exceptions -I../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0 -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/src -I../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/include -g -Wall -O2 -D NDEBUG -o obj/IESpecError.o src/exceptions/IESpecError.cpp
mkdir bin
g++ -shared -lpthread -L../../../../../third-party/g3log/2017-07-18_g3log/build -lg3logger -flto  -o bin/libfc.so  obj/BasicOctetArray.o obj/EncodePlan.o obj/FileExportDestination.o obj/IETemplate.o obj/IEType.o obj/InfoElement.o obj/InfoModel.o obj/libfc.o obj/PlacementExporter2.o obj/PlacementTemplate.o obj/TemplateState.o obj/UdpSocketExportDestination.o obj/Exception.o obj/ExportError.o obj/FormatError.o obj/IESpecError.o ../../../../../third-party/boost/1.66.0/stage/lib/libboost_system.a
```

Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The poster seems to understand what undefined references are, and hasn't made any of the common simple mistakes as far as I can see. If some answer there explains this specific problem, which? Voting to reopen for now.

Comment: @aschepler The answer is in the dupe. Order of the linked binaries matters.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ test.cpp appears before -lfc on the command line. Isn't that correct?

Comment: It does look suspicious that nm reports the symbols as "t" and not "T", and readelf says "LOCAL". A lowercase nm code usually means internal linkage. (But I'm not sure how you would even end up with internal linkage for class member functions.)

Comment: @aschepler You are right order is correct

Comment: So it could be helpful to see how libfc.so was built.  (And by the way, on Unix/ELF systems, a lib*.a file is a "static library" and a lib*.so file is a "shared library".)

Comment: @aschepler Updated with more information about how libfc.so was built.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244428/hiding-symbol-names-in-library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52216452/5769463

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> libfc::InfoModel & model = libfc::InfoModel::instance();
>                  ^
> /tmp/ccFtLDxc.o: In function `main':
> test.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `libfc::InfoModel::instance()'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

Combined with `-fvisibility=hidden` (and friends):

```
$ nm -gCD ...

0000000000012980 t libfc::InfoModel::add(std::string const&)
0000000000010a60 t libfc::InfoModel::instance()
00000000000106f0 t libfc::InfoModel::initTypes()
...
```

I believe all this means is you have hidden your `InfoModel` class and it is no longer visible. I am guessing you manually added `-fvisibility=hidden` (and friends) but did not edit the source files and add `DLL_PUBLIC` (per the [GCC Visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) wiki).

I think the easiest fix for you is to build the static archive *without* visibility. I.e., don't use `-fvisibility=hidden` (and friends). Then, when you build your shared object/plug-in that uses the static archive, use `-fvisibility=hidden` (and friends) and include `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL` linker flags. The extra linker flags will ensure you don't re-export the symbols from the static archives.

Your source files for the plugin would use `DLL_PUBLIC` (per the [GCC Visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) wiki). The makefile recipe would use something like:

```
$(PLUGIN): $(PLUG_OBJS) $(FRAME_OBJS) $(OUTPUT)
   $(CXX) -shared -o $(OUTPUT) $(CXXFLAGS) $(PLUG_OBJS) $(FRAME_OBJS) $(BOOST_LIBS) $(LDFLAGS) -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL
```

Then you can examine what is exported from your shared object/plug-in with something like:

```
nm -gCD libplugin.so | grep ' T '
```

Unfortunately there's no way to avoid the `nm -gCD libplugin.so | grep ' T '` wart. I was just on the Binutils mailing list looking for a better way to display the exports.

A GCC issue report was recently opened against the docs for visibility at [Issue 87190, Feedback on documentation for symbol visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87190). Also see [Linker exposing private symbols](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2018-08/msg00443.html) on the Binutils mailing list.

---

Some additional quick comments...

> ```
> CPP = g++
> ```

`CPP` is the preprocessor. Use `CXX`.

> ```
> FLAGS = ...
> ```

Use `CXXFLAGS` for C++ projects. Your C++ recipes might look like:

```
SRCS = $(sort $(wildcard *.cpp))
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
```