# Undefined reference when linking a .o file to a .elf file

Tags: linker, linker-errors, ld, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have an `.o` file compiled from a **C** project which references a function named `init_static_pools`. I use `objdump -t` to show its symbol dependency info:

> 00000000         **UND**  00000000 init_static_pools

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244428/hiding-symbol-names-in-library), the **UND** simply says "*I need someone else to provide me that function*".

So I linked this `.o` file to an `.elf` file, which contains the definition of `init_static_pools`. The `objdump -t` shows that the symbol is *indeed* in this file:

> 00004dcf **g     F** .text    00000048              init_static_pools

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244428/hiding-symbol-names-in-library), the `g` and `F` flags mean it is a **glbal function**. I guess it means this function can be **statically linked**.

I tried to link the `.o` file and the `.elf` file with below command line:

> /usr/bin/c++    -m32    -rdynamic   **unittest1.o**    -o unittest1   **target.elf**
>   lib/libgtest.a  lib/libgtest_main.a -lpthread

I got below error:

> unittest1.cc:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `init_static_pools'

**The function is just in the .so file, why it cannot be linked?**

Could this be related to the different symbol resolving mechanisms between dynamic and static linking? Because I use `objdump -f` and see that the `target.elf` is a dynamic object. As shown below:

> target.elf:     file format elf32-i386
>
> architecture: i386, flags 0x00000150:
>
> HAS_SYMS, **DYNAMIC**, D_PAGED
>
> start address 0x00001144

### ADD 1 - 9:17 AM 11/6/2019

Based on the comment by **@EmployedRussian**, I tried `readelf`.

For the `target.elf`, it only contains 1 line saying:

> 486: 00004dcf    72 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 init_static_pools

For the `unittest1.o`, it contains 2 lines saying:

> 0000002d  0000fb04 R_386_PLT32       00000000   init_static_pools

and

> 251: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND init_static_pools

And for the completion, their headers are:

`target.elf`:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x1144
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          246936 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         43
  Section header string table index: 42
```

`unittest1.o`:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              REL (Relocatable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          36988 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         0
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         262
  Section header string table index: 261
```

So far, I cannot tell the root cause of the linkage failure yet. Luckily I just found the [series](https://lwn.net/Articles/276782/) on linker by *the* [Ian Lance Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_%28linker%29). Hope that can enlighten me. But it will take some time I guess.

### ADD 2 - 10:33 AM 11/6/2019

Based on @EmployedRussian's reply, I tried below commands:

```
nm    target.elf | grep init_static_pools
nm -D target.elf | grep init_static_pools
```

Just as @EmployedRussian suspected, the second command line doesn't have output. So that means *target.elf is not exporting init_static_pools in its dynamic symbol table, and that makes the symbol not eligible for linking to from outside of target.elf.*

Below are some flags related to the linking of the `target.elf`:

```
-Wl,-T zephyr/linker.cmd  (this is quite long, but it seems to be mostly layout info)

-Wl,-Map=target_prebuilt.map

-Wl,--whole-archive

-Wl,--gc-sections

-Wl,--build-id=none

-Wl,--sort-common=descending

-Wl,--sort-section=alignment

-ldl

-lm
```

Or should I check the compile flags as well?

And I found the [--export-all-symbols](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-_002d_002dexport_002dall_002dsymbols), [--export-dynamic](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-_002d_002dexport_002ddynamic), [--gc-keep-exported](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-_002d_002dgc_002dkeep_002dexported) options, I am trying them.

It seems the `--export-all-symbols` is ignored. I guess it is meant for DLL.

I put `--export-dynamic` and `--gc-keep-exported` together, and the build can pass.
But the `nm -D` still shows below message:

> target.elf : no symbols

### ADD 3 - 11:16 AM 11/6/2019

An article about dynamic symbol table (.dynsym) and symbol table(.symtab).
https://blogs.oracle.com/solaris/inside-elf-symbol-tables-v2

Some quote:

> In fact, in the days before sharable libraries and dynamic linking,
>   none of it was needed at runtime. There was a single, non-allocable
>   symbol table (reasonably named "symtab"). When dynamic linking was
>   added to the system, the original designers faced a choice: Make the
>   symtab allocable, or provide a second smaller allocable copy. The
>   symbols needed at runtime are a small subset of the total, so a second
>   symbol table saves virtual memory in the running process. This is an
>   important consideration. Hence, a second symbol table was invented for
>   dynamic linking, and consequently named "dynsym".

So, I think the `.dynsym` is meant for **dynamic linking at runtime**. But I think I am expecting my `unittest1.o` and `target.elf` to be **staticly linked at build time**.

So it leads me to this question: **Can I statically link to an `.ELF` file?** On Windows, I usually statically link to a `.lib` file rather than a `.DLL` file. The `.ELF` file here looks more like a `.DLL`. And btw, my build process also generate a `libtarget.a` file. Should I use it instead of `target.elf`?

Unfortunately, I tried `nm -t` and `readelf -s` on `libtarget.a`, neither of them show the existence of `init_static_pools`.

BTW, if you know something about my issue, feel free to drop some hint. Thanks!

Comment: You should *never* use `objdump` on `ELF` systems: it maps `ELF` to ancient constructs (it was written in an era of `COFF`). Instead, always use `readelf` which tells you what is *actually* happening.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Thanks for the hint. I will try Read ELF today.

Comment: @EmployedRussian btw I remember I read somewhere that readelf is developed without using the bfd lib while objdump with it. The reason is for comparison or something.

Answer (score 1):

> For the target.elf, it only contains 1 line saying:
>   `486: 00004dcf 72 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 init_static_pools`

Unfortunately, this still isn't sufficient to tell for sure what's happening.

To tell for sure, run these two commands:

```
nm    target.elf | grep init_static_pools
nm -D target.elf | grep init_static_pools
```

I suspect that the first command would produce output, while the second one would not.

If that's the case, then `target.elf` is *not* exporting `init_static_pools` in its dynamic symbol table, and that makes the symbol not eligible for linking to from outside of `target.elf`.

As to how you ended up with this symbol not exported, I can only guess (since you didn't provide the link command used to link it). You are likely using a linker script which hides it.

Comment: Thanks. Your suspect is right. I updated my question with some linking flags.

Comment: I think the actual answer lies in `linker.cmd` somewhere. It's also not clear how you ended up with `ET_DYN` object (given lack of `--shared` on your link line).