# What is the use of local symbols in the symbol table of an object file?

Tags: c, linker, elf, symbol-table

From the question ([Hiding symbol names in library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244428/hiding-symbol-names-in-library)), I thought static functions are removed from an object file's symbol table when compiled with optimization (maybe because compilers assume it is a release build). The below is a slighltly modified source code from ([Hiding symbol names in library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244428/hiding-symbol-names-in-library)) and the symbol table of the compiled object file.

```
// compile with gcc -c -O2 -o file.o file.c

extern int a();
extern int b();

static int f_b1(){
return a();
}

static int f_b3(){
return b();
}
```

```
test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 test.c
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack        0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment       0000000000000000 .comment
```

However, it seems such disappearance was caused just because both f_b1 and f_b3 are not used. Evidently, if they are called by a non-static function as below, their symbols re-appear in the symbol table (i.e. objdump -t file.o).

```
extern int a();
extern int b();

static int __attribute__ ((noinline)) f_b1(){
return a();
}

static int __attribute__ ((noinline)) f_b2(){
return b();
}

void f_b3(){
    f_b1();
    f_b2();
}
```

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 test.c
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l     F .text  0000000000000007 f_b1
0000000000000010 l     F .text  0000000000000007 f_b2
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack        0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame      0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment       0000000000000000 .comment
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 a
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 b
0000000000000020 g     F .text  0000000000000013 f_b3
```

So, by default, it seems a compiler emits the symbols of static functions into the symbol table even with optimization. Then, what is the use of such local symbols? **Are they really required during linking stage** (I don't see why they are required since call and jump are performed in an eip-relative way, isn't it?)?

Comment: Static symbols can be very useful during debugging.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. However, I'm wondering if that's the only reason why compiler emits that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are they really required during linking stage

No. They are only there to help debugging.

You can confirm this by using `objcopy --strip-unneeded test.o test1.o` -- the symbols will be removed, but you can still link `test1.o` into the final binary just as you could with `test.o`.